# Weird issue where form field loses focus to previous form field even with JS disabled

Tags: custom-post-types, jquery, javascript

I've never seen a problem like this in my 12 years of working on the web. Even with Javascript disabled (in all browsers, with all users on different computers), a field that gets focus then loses it to the previous form field. I thought I had some rogue jQuery somewhere but couldn't find any... then decided to disable Javascript and see what happens. The same problem exists.

What the deuce kind of wizardry is this?!?

Attached is a link to a screencast demonstrating the issue. Note that the first bit shows the problem with JS enabled (as demonstrated by the presence of TinyMCE toolbar) and the second is without (as demonstrated WITHOUT TinyMCE).

Help?!

http://screencast.com/t/y2NfpGa8z

Answer (score 1):

without seeing the actual source, I'd guess that the field labels are interfering with the fields. mouse down on a field will focus it, but mouse up on a label will focus the label's associated field.

Comment: The relevant source in the PHP is: https://gist.github.com/2120588 - Relevant generated HTML: https://gist.github.com/2120647

Comment: Solved. It was invalidly closed label tags... The closing tag was just `<label>` instead of `</label>`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once so i hope i am on the mark when
i had the same ID to diferent input fields...

Try checking the input fields for duplicate ID's.

```
<input type="" id="numberone" />
<input type="" id="numbertwo" />
<input type="" id="numberthree" />

Or in the case of meta boxes  
(example from some meta boxes i created)  

array(
'name' => __('Usage Instructions', 'sagive'),
'desc' => __('Please Insert all available data on this website to achive a great look for the business page', 'sagive'),
'type' => 'title',
),
array(
    'name' => __('Website URL', 'sagive'),
    'desc' => __('(example: http://www.sagive.co.il)', 'sagive'),
    'id'   => $prefix . 'numberone',
    'type' => 'numberthree',
),  
array(
    'name'    => __('NoFollow Tag', 'sagive'),
    'desc'    => __('Would you like to use NoFollow for his website?', 'sagive'),
    'id'      => $prefix . 'numbertwo',
    'type'    => 'radio',
    'options' => array(
        array( 'name' => __('Yes', 'sagive'), 'value' => 'yes', ),
        array( 'name' => __('No', 'sagive'), 'value' => 'no', ),
    ),
),
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Best Regards, Sagive

Comment: All the fields and labels are created automatically from array keys and the HTML/labels do line up. :\

Comment: hmm... well if i were you my next step is to change the plugin folder name temporary to check if something i cant think of is loaded in the background..

Comment: is that possible for you to try or is it an online site?